# Can I view the public API of my class library in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Using the Object Browser, I see everything, public, internal, private.  How can I see only the public API of my class library?

If not, is there another tool I can use to browse my class library's public API?  I'm trying to get an outside-in view of my library.

Comment: It's a pity there's no simple way to see a public API of your module in .net/C# in still vs 2022. Object Browser or Class View show you everything mixed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By referencing the class library in another project, when I view it in that Object Browser, it shows the public API only.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) and limit the visibility options under 'View' -> 'Options' -> 'Browser' to 'Public items only':

[image]

Comment: Downloaded a Reflector trial and it worked well.  I'm surprised there's no tool specifically for looking at libraries from a consumer's POV.  Thinking about writing one myself.

Answer (score 5):

In the object browser to filter only public items on an individual class. This doesn't filter the left hand pane of the browser so you still see private types there.

[image: Object browser filtering]

You can also use the ILDASM tool that ships with the Windows SDK. This gives a bunch more filtering options and filters things from the tree fiew completely. It's really a disassembly viewer to it's not as pretty.

[image: ILDASM]

You can download the SDK from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924

It will install in: 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\ildasm.EXE

You can also use Reflector. This used to be free but now seems to be a paid product that will uninstall the free version when it updates. IMO reflector is the best tool for this but only if you feel like buying it. It starts at $35 for the basic version http://www.reflector.net/.

Answer (score 1):

The [ApiChange](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2010/06/03/140207.aspx) tool allows you to query on the command line and to export the results to [Excel](http://apichange.codeplex.com/documentation).
E.g.

```
ApiChange.exe -wt "public class *" <YourDll.dll> -in gac:\system.dll -excel
```

This will search for all public classes in your dll and search for users of your types in system.dll. There will be none but you will get a full listing for all of your classes.

The type query format is defined by:
**Visibility ClrType TypeName**

- Visibility can be public | internal
- ClrType can be class | interface | struct | enum
- TypeName is the full qualified type name or a partial name or only a namespace query. The string after the last . is treated as the actual type name.

Valid Type Queries are

- System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
- Stopwatch
- stopwatch
- stopw*
- System.*.Stopwatch
- public class *

Yours,
  Alois Kraus